# MySQL server connection not working from perl script using DBI but works from command line and GUI too

Tags: mysql, perl

I am trying to connect to MySQL database on a remote server using the Perl DBI AND DBD::MySQL Modules,but getting the error below

"DBI connect('database=user_rohan;host=hostname;port=3306','rohan',...) failed: Can't connect to MySQL server"

I am logged in on my remote server through command line,since I did not find any option to login to the server in the Perl script.Below is my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;
use DBD::mysql;
my $host = 'hostname';
my $user = 'rohan';
my $dbh   =DBI>connect("dbi:mysql:database=user_rohan;host=$host;port=3306","$user","password", {'RaiseError' => 1});
```

While,Installing the Perl DBD:MySQL modules,I faced a lot of issues but was able  to install the module successfully and ran my tests as well.
I find a similar question asked earlier but was not able to solve from reading the answers in its comments.

Thanks,

Rohan

Comment: @rojan What is the IP of remote server?.

Comment: Hi Jhonathan The IP is 10.171.30.178.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to connect to a local MySQL database so the problem was not in the Perl Modules and nor the script.

I was not able to directly connect to the Remote MySQL database because the port is blocked. In these cases,we need to use port ssh forwarding.

ssh -L 3307:localhost:3306 USERNAME@hostname

Then set the host = 127.0.0.1 (localhost)and the port to 3307 in your perl script.

Answer (score 0):

Please check that your connection is correct. Is the hostname correct? Is the username correct? Is the password correct? Is the port correct? Please try it out with a mysql client and if you can successfully connect to your MySQL database using the same data, then it is a bug in your code. Otherwise something is wrong with your connection data. This is a general approach, this is not the last time you are facing this problem, but if you know the right approach you will not need to ask a question about this one on a programming forum.

Comment: The details are correct,and I mentioned in my SUBJECT  itself that I am able to connect through command line and GUI(mysql client)

Comment: @rohanbareja, please think ahead. People will have the same problem in the future, my answer will help them, as it describe the complete thought process one must run through to solve the problem of this kind. In your case it is a problem in your source-code then, so you should look at some perl script examples solving this kind of problem and replace their connection parameters with yours. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Rojan test with

```
my $host = '10.171.30.178';
```

or

```
my $host = '127.0.0.1';
```

Comment: Jonathan,I have the IP in my code,just did not mention it here earlier.Its not working with IP.

Comment: @rohanbareja If you do ping to hostname in your terminal. This resolve to what IP?. The "hostname" must translate to IP. One option is edit file /etc/hosts and add "127.0.0.1  hostname"

Comment: It resolves to 10.171.30.178 to the hostname.  Also "127.0.0.1" is added in the /etc/hosts.I replaced this IP with 10.171.30.178 but getting this error: DBI connect('database=user_rohan;host=127.0.0.1;port=3306','rohan',...) failed: Access denied for user 'rohan'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Answer (score 0):

my $dbh DBI>connect("dbi:mysql:database=user_rohan;host=$host;port=3306","$user","password", {'RaiseError' => 1});

Maby typing error ?

```
$dbh = DBI->connect($data_source, $username, $auth, \%attr);
```

And DBI::mysql necessarily